# CSV file line count not working in PHP

Tags: php, file, csv, count

I have a webpage that needs to count the number of lines in a CSV file, but the following code isn't working:

```
$linecount = count(file("sample.csv"));
var_dump($linecount);
```

When I run this code, the code returns the number 1, but there are 8 lines in `sample.csv`. Does anybody know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Calling `vardump(file("sample.csv"))` might provide some insight. Is the entire file being read into the first item in the array?

Comment: What does `print $linecount` output?

Comment: @negacao Thanks, the entire file was read into the first item of the array.

Comment: *"When I run this code, the code returns the number 1"* - You mean `int(1)`, correct? What platform are you running this under? the question's unclear and for future visitors.

Comment: @PhiladelphiaRegionalWeather can you also vote-up the answer? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `sample.csv` file created in mac/linux you might want to consider setting `auto_detect_line_endings` to `ON`.

[From the manual:](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings)

> `auto_detect_line_endings` boolean
>         When turned on, PHP will examine the data read by fgets() and file() to see if it is using
>         Unix, MS-Dos or Macintosh line-ending conventions.

Another option (if you don't want to use this) is to read the file and split the lines by all new-line options (`\r\n|\r|\n`):

```
$linecount = count(preg_split("/\r\n|\r|\n/", file_get_contents("sample.csv")));
```

Comment: Why not use `PHP_EOL` instead of `/\r\n|\r|\n/` ?

Comment: @PedroLobito, mostly because the `PHP_EOL` is platform specific. If you are running the PHP on windows, but the `sample.csv` was created on mac, the new-line in that CSV file will be `\r` (and this is what caused the error).

Comment: The `auto_detect_line_endings` will "fix" this problem

Comment: Yes, `auto_detect_line_endings` will do it.